# How to add two values from list in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

This is a list of pizza prices

```
  const pizzaPrices = {
    'margherita': 5.5,
    'pepperoni': 7.5,
    'vegetarian': 6.5,
  };
```

how to calculate the total for a given order.
if margherita and pepperoni then it should be 13$.

```
const order = ['margherita', 'pepperoni'];
```

how do i add to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  const pizzaPrices = {
    'margherita': 5.5,
    'pepperoni': 7.5,
    'vegetarian': 6.5,
  };
  const order = ['margherita', 'pepperoni'];
  var total=0.0;
  order.forEach((item){
    total+=pizzaPrices[item]??0.0;  
  });
  print("Total : "+total.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few approaches you can calculate the total. One way would be to use `fold`:

```dart
final total =
    order.fold<double>(0.0, (prev, elem) => prev + pizzaPrices[elem]!);
```

Another way would be to loop through the order and add up the total imperatively:

```dart
var total = 0.0;
for (final elem in order) {
  total += pizzaPrices[elem]!;
}
```

In order to add to your list, you would call the `add` method on the list:

```dart
order.add('vegetarian');
```

However, a `const` list cannot be modified, so you would have to change `order` to be declared as either `final` or `var`:

```dart
final order = ['margherita', 'pepperoni'];
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you use this than you don't have to define your own ```fold`` function.

```
var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

You can visit this for more clearity, https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1649

Or

```
num sum = 0;
for (num e in [1,2,3]) {
  sum += e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const pizzaPrices = {
    'margherita': 5.5,
    'pepperoni': 7.5,
    'vegetarian': 6.5,
  };
  const order = ['margherita', 'pepperoni'];
  
  var total=0.0;
  order.forEach((item){
     pizzaPrices.forEach((name,price){
       if(name==item){
         total=total+price;
       }
     });
  });
  
  print("Total : "+total.toString());
```

Comment: This does not make efficient use of the map. Instead of looping over every map entry using `foreach` just subscript `[]` into the `pizzaPrices` map using the `item` variable.

Comment: yes you are right please check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void main() {
  const pizzaPrices = {
    'margherita': 5.5,
    'pepperoni': 7.5,
    'vegetarian': 6.5,
  };

  var x = pizzaPrices['margherita'];
  var y = pizzaPrices['pepperoni'];

  List xy = [];

  xy.add(x);
  xy.add(y);

  double somme = 0;

  xy.forEach((var element) => somme += element);

  print(somme);
}
```